# Why does this sentence "feel" wrong

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I saw this sentence. It "feels" wrong, but I can't put my finger on why.

1. Thanks for being part of the family and to help build a network.

I feel that it should be:

2. Thanks for being part of the family and helping (to?) build a network.

Or even:

3. Thanks for being part of the family and helping in building a network.

Am I correct, or am I being too pedantic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't just feel wrong. It is wrong.

Individual parts of such sentences should work on their own. This is not the case here:

"Thanks to help build a network." is incorrect and, as you said, should be "Thanks for helping build a network". Your other suggestions are also correct.

Comment: This answer is unclear and lacks any support for its assertion. The fact that its conclusion may be correct does not alter this. How is the poster to know whether the answer is correct?